# What does the following Array initialization syntax actually create?

Tags: javascript

What does the following actually create?

I ask because it cannot be enumerated with `Array#foreach` and it is represented (misleadingly?) in Chrome console as `[undefined x 10]`.

```
const arr = new Array(10);
```

Comment: `console.log(arr);`. It will create an array with size 10 and undefined values. https://jsfiddle.net/o9f25Ljz/

Comment: No, i don't think it will. Please try it.

Comment: What exactlyis the question? 10x `[undefined]` is exactly whats *supposed* to happen in that case. You never initailize any contents of the array.

Comment: The runtime distinguishes array elements that have been explicitly assigned values from those that haven't.

Comment: @BenAston check my updated fiddle

Comment: The representation in the fiddle is misleading IMO because of the behavior described in Pointy's comment.

Comment: You can't enumerate, because array doesn't contain any element. You are confused because it looks like there are 10 `undefined` values, but it's not the case, there are nothing, *"holes"*.

Comment: So what is the point of this syntax? Solely for the use case of code that wants to rely on the length property as a bound?

Comment: Well the point is to create a new empty array. If you define , says, a new array of String or size 10. `new String[10]` You will have 10 pointer available for "filling" in your case you made a constant out of the same concept. of course you can't fill them. If you would remove the `const` it would be  "fillable"

Comment: `const` is shallow, so you are not correct on that point. Arrays are dynamic in JS, so the size concept is fluid.

Comment: `const` variables cannot be re-assigned. Object contents can, meanwhile, be changed.

Answer (score 3):

The `Array` object has three different possible constructor actions:

1. `new Array()`
2. `new Array(<multiple arguments)`
3. `new Array(<one argument>)` (placed as last because of its nature - see further)

The behavior of the constructor depends of the arguments provided to that constructor. All those three actions uses [`ArrayCreate`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arraycreate) during the constructor action. From the link:

> The abstract operation ArrayCreate with argument length (a positive integer) and optional argument proto is used to specify the creation of new Array exotic objects.

This function accepts two arguments: `len` (length) and `proto` which is used to create an array object. (I won't go deeper here because it would be more complex). The `len` argument is more important in this situation. When we are looking to the constructor actions individually, you have

### `new Array()`

Here, an object is constructed by `ArrayCreate(0, proto)`, thus an empty array with `.length = 0`.

### `new Array(<multiple arguments>)`

Here, an object is constructed by `ArrayCreate(#of args, proto)`. If you provide 3 arguments, then you get an array with `.length = 3`. This array is then populated with the provided arguments. Do you give 5 arguments? You get `.length = 5`. So the `.length` property depends of the number of the arguments.

### `new Array(<one argument>)`

This one is quite different. It has two cases. At init, an array object is created with `ArrayCreate(0, proto)` like if you're using `new Array()`. Still we have an argument here to use.

If the argument is a *non-numeric* value, then the effect is same as point 2. This argument is being added to the constructed object (like a `.push()` operation. So `new Array('hello')` or `new Array('10')` gives you an array object with `.length = 1`

Now, the thing is very different when you give a *numeric* argument `new Array(10)`, which gives in Chrome `[undefined x 10]`. Why? Because when the argument is numeric (and valid), this function is being called: [`Set(O,P,V,Throw)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set-o-p-v-throw). This "magic" function sets the property `P` of object `O` with the value `V`. (The `Throw` is a flag to indicate " *throw error or not?* " question).

If the argument is a length, `set(<constructed array>, 'length', <argument>, true)` is being executed. So the `.length` property returns the argument value while there is nothing being preserved in the memory. End result: you have an object with a fake `.length` property... A side-effect of this is that using `.push` adds an element to the 10th index (if `.length` was 10). Now you have an array with 11 elements: 10 "empty" slots and an element that you've just pushed.

So what does the browsers do with an array with a "fake" `.length` property? They cannot iterate it correctly. So they provide a failsafe way: display "has 10 elements but are empty" like chrome does with `[undefined x 10]` or firefox: `Array [ <10 empty slots>]`

If you ask me why this is being standardized in the specs, then I would respond with "I don't know". It is one of the weirdest decision (among other ones that I have encountered) that is being standardized in ECMAScript.

Answer (score 1):

The following two snippets are equivalent:

```
const arr = new Array(10)
```

and

```
const arr = [,,,,,,,,,,]
```

as can be demonstrated here:

```js
const arr1 = new Array(10)
const arr2 = [,,,,,,,,,,]

let empty1 = true

for (let index = 0; empty1 && index < arr1.length; index++) {
  if (arr1.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
    empty1 = false
  }
}

let empty2 = true

for (let index = 0; empty1 && index < arr2.length; index++) {
  if (arr2.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
    empty2 = false
  }
}

console.log(empty1)
console.log(empty2)
```

This means that for all indices from `[0, length - 1]`, they don't actually exist on the array because `arr.hasOwnProperty(index)` is `false`. This is distinguished from this example:

```
const arr = new Array(10).fill()
```

demonstrated here:

```js
const arr = new Array(10).fill()

console.log(arr.every((_, index) => arr.hasOwnProperty(index)))
```

So if you want to initialize each index in a *constructed* array with `undefined`, just call `.fill()` without any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The `Array` constructor when supplied with a single integer value creates an `Array` instance with the `length` own-property set to that value.

Host environments like browsers can choose to render this as they choose. V8 chooses `[undefined x 10]` which is misleading because it implies there are ten instances of the predefined `undefined` value in an ordered sequence.

This is not the case.

[Array#foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) use the enumerable integer indices AND the `length` own-property value to enumerate the values of an array.

Because this specific `Array` constructor syntax does not initialize any integer properties on the `Array` object, they fail to enumerate `Array`s initialized in this manner.

I can only presume that this syntax is soley present to enable code patterns that rely on the `length` own-property of the `Array` instance  WITHOUT needing any keys or values to be initialized.

Comment: from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach : `forEach() executes the provided callback once for each element present in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays).` - if you want to add to your post

Comment: You state that the constructor doesn't initializes any integer properties, but then why `arr[0]` outputs something? -> https://jsfiddle.net/o9f25Ljz/1/

Comment: The value of a not-present property is `undefined`.

Comment: if I do `console.log(newArr[0]);` does output nothing(without initialization of newArr) - not `undefined`